# Help Debugging an Ajax Server Control Client Script

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls

I am writing an Ajax Server Control in ASP.NET C# 4.0 in VS 2010.

After writing the javascript prototype class by hand, I don't know of a way to compile and debug file.  To see why my "onclick" event doesn't work.

I'm creating an Ajax Server control by inheriting from Control & IScriptControl, and trying to get an onclick event handler to work.  The written control is actually a "DIV".  Can someone tell me why it doesn't work?

Thanks

```
public class FrebbleSquare : Control, IScriptControl 
    {
.
.
.
IEnumerable<ScriptReference> IScriptControl.GetScriptReferences()
        {
            ScriptReference oRef1 = new ScriptReference("FrebbleAjaxControls.FrebbleSquare.js", this.GetType().Assembly.ToString());
            ScriptReference oRef2 = new ScriptReference("FrebbleAjaxControls.prototype.js", this.GetType().Assembly.ToString());
            ScriptReference oRef3 = new ScriptReference("FrebbleAjaxControls.scriptaculous.js", this.GetType().Assembly.ToString());
            ScriptReference oRef4 = new ScriptReference("FrebbleAjaxControls.effects.js", this.GetType().Assembly.ToString());

            return new ScriptReference[] { oRef1, oRef2, oRef3, oRef4 };
        }


        IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> IScriptControl.GetScriptDescriptors()
        {
            ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor("FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare", this.ClientID);

            return new ScriptDescriptor[] { descriptor };
        }

}


JAVASCRIPT CLIENT FILE :


Type.registerNamespace('FrebblesAjax');

FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare = function (element) {

    FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare.initializeBase(this, [element]);


}


FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare.prototype =
{
    initialize: function () {

        FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

        this._onclickHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onClick);

        $addHandlers(this.get_element(),
                     { 'click': this._onClick,
                     },
                     this);

    },

    dispose: function () {

        $clearHandlers(this.get_element());

        FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    _onClick: function (e) {

        alert('it worked!');

    }

}


FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare.registerClass('FrebblesAjax.FrebbleSquare', Sys.UI.Control);

if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

Comment: why "writing the javascript prototype class by hand"? why not use prototype (if needed)?

Comment: why you are searching a "way to compile and debug file"? Which file? why compile it? java script isn't compiled?

Comment: first inspect the html delivered to your browser. popular for this is firebug in firefox. Look at the html element in question. see, if your handler was installed properly. I suppose its not. Than go back to asp and start digging there.

Comment: Sorry, I should've said intellisense for prototype..not compile...ill try and see if the handler was installed... thx

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Firefox, download the [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/). When the page loads, right-click on the element that you created and select "inspect element". This way you can see all the structure, properties, and functions of the DOM as it currently exists. This is usually preferable to "view source" when you're working with JavaScript. You should be able to see which event handlers are bound and set breakpoints in the JavaScript debugger.